# Change Maven local repository in Eclipse Workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven

I just moved an eclipse project to a workspace on an encrypted drive. I have a second workspace with some other projects which do not need to be encrypted. The problem is that both of them end up in the same .m2 local repository (/home/USER/.m2/repository) which is not encrypted. 
I need to change the maven local repository only in one workspace and not in the other, so I can't just change the global settings, is there a way to do it?

Comment: You have to change your settings.xml file in your home directory `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` and change `localRepository` in it accordingly to your needs...I would recommend to create a git repository in `$HOME/.m2/ ` exclude `repository` and make two branches like `usual` and `encrypted` which contain the appropriate settings.xml file...You can of course add an command line parameter to each call of maven like `-Dmaven.repo.local=...` but I can't recommend cause I bet you will mis is sometimes...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for the reply, but that's actually what I can't do. I already wrote in my question that I need two separate settings to be used in two different workspaces.

Comment: This is what I exactly suggested via git branches...

Comment: You could also use two separate Eclipse installations.

Answer (score 0):

It was much easier than I thought. The preferences you set in Eclipse (Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings) are stored within the workspace.
So I created a second workspace, then I made a copy of the repository and I created a settings.xml for the second repository.
If I want to see all the projects side by side I start one Eclipse instance, then I start the second, I get an error because the current workspace is in use, but at that point I can select the other workspace and I can have two instances running at the same time pointing to two different local repositories (but still I didn't try complex builds).